# I am trying to print array inside object using map function but I get :Cannot read property map of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, map-function

I'm trying to print the properties of Selectedproduct object inside Modal section and every thing works well until it reaches to "description" array property , it shows me "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". eventhough when I use console.log(Selectedproduct) the description property appears normally,but when I code console.log(Selectedproduct.description) I dont know why it consider it as undefined .can you please tell me why it can't see the description as stand alone property ?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FormatCurrency from "../Components/util";
import Slide from "react-reveal/Slide";
import Modal from "react-modal";
import Zoom from "react-reveal/Zoom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { GetProducts } from "../Actions/ItemsActions";
import { AddToCart } from "../Actions/CartActions";
class Products extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      show: false,
      Selectedproduct: {},
    };
  }
  showModal = (product) => {
    console.log(product);
    this.setState({ show: true, Selectedproduct: product });
  };

  hideModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.GetProducts();
  }
  render() {
    const { Selectedproduct } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Slide left cascade={true}>
          {!this.props.products ? (
            <div> Loading..</div>
          ) : (
            <ul className="products">
              {this.props.products.map((product) => (
                <li key={product._id}>
                  <div className="product">
                    <a href={"#" + product._id}>
                      <img
                        src={product.image}
                        alt={product.title}
                        onClick={() => this.showModal(product)}
                      ></img>
                      <p>{product.title}</p>
                    </a>
                    <div className="product-price">
                      <div> {FormatCurrency(product.price)}</div>

                      <button
                        onClick={() => this.props.AddToCart(product)}
                        className="button primary overlay"
                      >
                        {" "}
                        Add to cart
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
        </Slide>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.show} onRequestClose={this.hideModal}>
          <Zoom>
            <button className="close-modal" onClick={this.hideModal}>
              x
            </button>
            <div className="product-details">
              <img
                src={Selectedproduct.image}
                alt={Selectedproduct.title}
              ></img>
              <div className="product-details-description">
                <p>{Selectedproduct.title}</p>
                <ul>
                {Selectedproduct.description.map((x)=>(<li>x</li>))}
                </ul>
                <div className="product-price">
                  <div>{FormatCurrency(Selectedproduct.price)}</div>
                  <button
                    className="button primary"
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.props.AddToCart(Selectedproduct);
                      this.hideModal();
                    }}
                  >
                    {" "}
                    Add to cart
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Zoom>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default connect((state) => ({ products: state.products.filterdItems }), {
  GetProducts,
  AddToCart,
})(Products);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as your state property seems still undefined at runtime.

```
{Selectedproduct.description.map((x)=>(<li>x</li>))}
```

replace with:

```
{Selectedproduct && Selectedproduct.description? Selectedproduct.description.map((x)=>(<li>x</li>)):null}
```

Comment: perfect ! thanks a lot I really appreciate it !
but can you explain why all of them was working fine but description not ?

Comment: Well the render() method will be called every time the state or prop changes. At the very beginning your state Selectedproduct is an empty object. .map() on description requires description to be an array but it was undefined at runtime. You could also set a default state for Selectedproduct to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

description is likely undefined. Instead of:

```js
                <ul>
                {Selectedproduct.description.map((x)=>(<li>x</li>))}
                </ul>
```

just put in this temporary code to try and see what your object really looks like:

```js
                <ul>
                console.dir("### DESCRIPTION IS:", Selectedproduct.description)
                </ul>
```

and the open your browser dev tools to see what this prints to the console.

#### UPDATE based on comment after using `console.log`:

If you are getting something like `availableColors: Array(2)` for Selectedproduct you cannot print an array out to your `<li>` tags. An array is not a string. You have to unnest the inner arrays first.

So if your structure is Selectedproduct.description.availableColors = ['blue', 'red'] just as an example, you will need code like:

```js
const { availableColors, otherAttribute1, otherAttribute2 } = Selectedproduct.description // destructure all array attributes from description
...
```

and then later in the component, do:

```js
                <ul>
                { availableColors.map(_ => <li>_</li>)}
                { otherAttribute1.map(_ => <li>_</li>)}
                { otherAttribute2.map(_ => <li>_</li>)}
                </ul>
```

Comment: I did it gave :
### DESCRIPTION IS: 'empty nothing here'
but I also tried console.log(Selectedproduct) it shows :

availableColors: Array(2)
0: "Gold"
1: "pink"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
brand: "Iphone"
description: Array(2)
0: "20.0 MP"
1: "2GHz"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
image: "/images/Iphone1.jpg"
price: 1049
title: "iPhone 11 Pro 256GB Gold"
__v: 0
_id: "zliAg4p-V"

Comment: @imadsuliman I updated the answer. Basically use console log to find which attributes of the description are arrays, and treat each one separately, as shown above. This assumes your sub-arrays are arrays of strings.